# Allow to "Add a comment" for users that opened a bounty on a question

Tags: support

[image]

Why -50 rep users no have permission to add a comment under answers after opening bounty by himself/herself? For example a user with 50 rep opened a **50 Bounty** for a question and in 99.99% reasons because he/she has a similar issue and he/she is looking for an answer, now one answer is coming and the user now has **0 reputation** and he/she CAN NOT add a comment there to tell the OP's answer if has new issue with the answer of him or not.

Why they are not allowed to add a comment while they receive a flag on their Inbox? Why the site not allow them? any fix expected.

Comment: Once you get a privilege, you will always have it. So once you reach 50 rep, you'll be able to comment even if you later dropped below 50. I might be mistaken though, as comments may be a special case.

Comment: @Dan no, privileges are tied to your current reputation. You go below the threshold, you lose the privilege. That's one of the sacrifices involved in a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about starting a bounty on another user's question, the same reputation requirements are there for comments, that is to say:

If it's not *their* question, they still need 50 rep to comment.

Comment: Yes it's another question. but how user(Bounty opened user) reply any issue to him?

Comment: You need 75 rep to be able to create your first bounty. You need 50 rep to be able to comment everywhere. Doesn't that mean that the user should be able to comment even if he drops below 50 since he already got the [comment everywhere](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege?

Comment: The same way anybody else would, earning the extra ≤25 reputation. I agree that it's a big awkward but perhaps that should be a consideration before placing the bounty.

Comment: I didn't know that consideration and I think new user don't know that:)

Comment: @Dan It certainly used to be the case that [placing bounties would lose you your privileges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/is-losing-privileges-after-placing-bounty-ok). That would include commenting.